# Calculations using C# and display it in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So basically, I want to calculate the total amount of my product in `textboxTotalamount` and display it in my data grid view(or my in sql database)
I have to code but not sure if it correct and where to place it also an confusion. I will put my code below.

```
public partial class OrderDetails : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = INFINITY; Initial Catalog = Stock; Integrated Security = True"); // making connection   
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter adapt;
    //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
   int OrderID = 0;                                                                                                                 

    public OrderDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OrderDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'stockDataSet.OrderDetails' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
       this.orderDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.stockDataSet.OrderDetails);

        // my code for calculating total amount
        int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantity.Text);
        decimal Unit_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtcost.Text);
        decimal Tax = Convert.ToDecimal(txttax.Text);
        decimal TotalAmount = (Qty * Unit_Price);
        decimal PercentageAmount = ((Unit_Price * Tax) / 100);
        TotalAmount = TotalAmount + PercentageAmount;
        txttotal.Text = TotalAmount.ToString();

    }

    private void btnorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //ud variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderDetails]([OrderName],[dateCreated],[StockID],[StockCode],[Quantity],[Cost],[TAX],[Total]) 
        VALUES(@OrderName,@dateCreated,@StockID,@StockCode,@Quantity,@Cost,@TAX,@Total)", con);


            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderName", txtordername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateCreated", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtpdatecreated.Value.Date;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockID", txtstockid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCode", txtstockcode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", txtcost.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAX", txttax.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", txttotal.Text);
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: "  + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrderDetails]", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
    private void ClearData()
    {
        txtordername.Text = "";
        txtstockid.Text = "";
        txtstockcode.Text = "";
        txtquantity.Text = "";
        txtcost.Text = "";
        txttax.Text = "";
        txttotal.Text = "";
        OrderID = 0;
    }


    private void orderDetailsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.orderDetailsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.stockDataSet);

    }

}
```

I want my total amount to be calculated in total amount text box and also saved in sql database.
user interface :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ryU.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the form? Maybe that helps to better understand your problem?

Comment: And have you considered decoupling the calculation from the form by moving it to a static method with the parameters qty, unitPrice and tax?

Comment: How many times do you need to be told to stop using [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)?

Comment: `I want my total amount to be ... saved in sql database` It is a bad practice to save calculated values which can be trivially recalculated.  Another professional tip you can disregard at your peril

Comment: @SMor it is what helping me right now and changing will just make it worse for me

Comment: @VolkmarRigo i tried but still not working out it messes up everything

Comment: I am a little confused here, what is the question here, are you not able to save the record into database or you are not able to populate the UI, after fetching from database?